# How to set multiple plugins for Cucumber Options from terminal of cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I set Cucumber options into my cucumber project below:
[image]

And I run test by mvn command line with -Dcucumber.options to override options of my prject:

```
mvn -f "pom.xml" -Dcucumber.options="--plugin json:report/cucumber.json,junit:target/junitreports.xml --tags @Login" test
```

But is show error:

```
Data provider mismatch
Method: runScenario([Parameter{index=0, type=cucumber.api.testng.PickleEventWrapper, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=cucumber.api.testng.CucumberFeatureWrapper, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(cucumber.api.testng.CucumberExceptionWrapper)cucumber.api.testng.CucumberExceptionWrapper@a0bf272]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Need to repeat the plugin option. Try this

```
--plugin json:report/cucumber.json --plugin junit:target/junitreports.xml
```

Comment: It work well. Thanks. I have a question: I run cucumber project with java command line: java -classpath "./lib/*";.;"./target/test-classes";"./target/classes" cucumber.api.cli.Main. Can I use @CucumberOptions that set up in my project?. Thanks.

Comment: No... runners are not used when u use main class to run cucumber. U will need to pass the options in the command itself

Comment: Thanks, because when I add -p "custom plugin" into terminal, receive of EventHandler<TestStepStarted> always run before beforeScenario of Hook, while expecting the opposite :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
@CucumberOptions(features= {"src/test/resources/features"}, glue= {"com"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "junit:target/JUNITReports/report.xml", "html:target/HTMLReports", "json:target/JSONReports/report.json"})
```